# Why are we still using JPEG?

Tags: compression, jpeg

JPEG was released in 1992. That's like 24 years back. Why haven't we shifted to some better format with better efficiency (say at least JPEG2000) yet?

Answer (score 2):

Usual problem. The content creators will switch when all the users have switched, and the users will switch when all the content creators have switched.